# Built-in array with variable size?

Tags: c++

Chapter 2.3.2 of The C++ Programming Language lists this constructor:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
};
```

As far as I know, the array size must be a constant expression, and `s` isn't. Is this legal? If so, why?

Comment: "*the array size must be a constant expression*" Since when?

Comment: You can dynamically allocate an array of a size which is not a constant expression. This is the reason why `new[]` was invented in the first place. A *declared * array size must be a constant, but `new` is not a declaration.

Comment: The size specified in a `new` expression is not required to be a constant expression.  Also, in your code, `elem` is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's legal because the array is allocated at runtime with the 'new' operator.

If you want to allocate an array at compile-time, you must provide a const int, or constant expression.

```
int count = 0;
cin >> count; 
int* a = new int[count];  // This is dynamic allocation happen at runtime.
int b[6];                 // This is static allocation and it happen at compile-time.
```

Comment: At block scope `int b[6];` is not static allocation. It would be automatic storage duration, "allocated" when the scope is entered, not at compile-time.